# Custom Markup to item in views

Tags: views, theming

I created a view that displays my user profile picture.  I created a template for this view using *'views-view-fields--name.tpl.php.*  This is the output I get.

```
<div class="view-content">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first views-row-last">
      <div class="field-content profile">
        <div class="user-picture">
          <img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/default_profile_picture.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is add a link to my image, like so:

```
 ...<a href="#"><img></img></a>...
```

But it keeps adding that line to just before the **"user-picture"** div, and I want it after it.  Is there any way to achieve this? Custom templates seems to not do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in the views ui.

- Create a custom field
- Hide the display of the image field
- Use tokens provided to add image field output to your custom field

**Example:**

```
<a href="#">[image_field]</a>
```

**UPDATE**

Also ensure the style options are set to none on the image field so you don't get any div wrappers.

Comment: Thanks Alex. But I tried that. Still prints out the '.user-picture' <div> before the <img>

Comment: Have you changed the style options for the image field? These should be set to 'none'.

Comment: What I have also done, is in the styling options, to select the field value and select -NONE- for HTML Element.  That removes the default <div> created around the field element.